# postfix domain troubles

Tags: postfix, mac-osx

So I just set up postfix for the first time (on OS X) and am getting this error"

```
Jan 25 15:45:09 localhost postfix/smtp[16372]: 204D448A29A: to=<email@example.com>,
relay=none, delay=30, delays=0.01/0.01/30/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred
(Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=domain.com type=MX:
Host not found, try again)
```

I can tell it's a DNS issue, but haven't really found a fix for it: :(

Reading, but don't quite understand:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/postfix-not-sending-mail-host-mx-records-not-found-673177/

edit:

So I changed my error to this:

```
Jan 25 16:23:37 localhost postfix/master[19505]:
fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock:
Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious what OSX version you're running, and what guide you used to install / configure postfix.  There's a bug with postfix in 10.8: http://blog.deversus.com/2012/07/fix-for-postfix-in-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/

Comment: I am using 10.8, and I installed it from this guide: http://www.esmejia.com/posts/20-send-real-mail-with-rails-from-your-development-environment-on-mac-os-x

Comment: or rather just followed directions

Comment: Now getting this error `Jan 25 16:23:37 localhost postfix/master[19505]: fatal: open lock file pid/master.pid: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable`